# Jquery ui datepicker clickable event dates

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to implement a calendar widget which has highlighted event dates with clickable events so it would display some additional information in a bootstrap popover. Something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zrz9t/1151/
Another additional requirement would be to work with jquery 2.1.3 as my provided jsfiddle doesn't work with it.

currently I have only highlighting the dates:

```
<script>
    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "lt" ] );

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var eventDates = [];
        eventDates.push((new Date( '06/06/2015' )).toISOString(),
                (new Date( '06/07/2015' )).toISOString()
        );

        var cal = $('#calendar');

        var locale = document.getElementById('_locale').innerHTML;

        cal.datepicker($.datepicker.regional[locale]);
        cal.datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
                return (eventDates.indexOf(date.toISOString()) > -1) ? [true, "event"] : [true, ""];
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm just a very beginner of JS/Jquery so maybe anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:
http://jsfiddle.net/jkdaza/gqha5vo8/7/

It's a modified version of the jsFiddle you have posted.

Basically, the issue you had when switching to jQuery 2.3.1 was due to the fact that you have to add a compatible jQuery UI version (see the [jQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/download/) for compatibility).

I haven't changed much on the example you have posted, just replaced a Bootstrap popover trigger, in the `onSelect` function:

```
...
if (event) {
    var options = {
           content: event.Title,
           container: 'body'
    }
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('destroy')
    .popover(options).popover('show');
}
...
```

Now, due to jQuery UI API, it seems really convoluted to transform a date table cell into a popover, hence, I have setup a generic popover which gets updated when a date (with event information attached to it) is selected.
However, with a bit of experimentation the above result should be achievable.